# Use ffmpeg to "overlay" a png on top of an entire video file

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editor, subtitles

I want to be able to use a command to "edit" a video to have an image over the entire length of the video. Some videos I download have hardcoded subtitles that I want to remove. But I also have a regular .srt to add subtitles back (which are better). Which means I can't just get out a notepad and cover the subs since that'd also cover the soft subtitles.

I found an old question that was similar, but their solution didn't seem to work for me. I'm not really sure what I'm doing, but here's what I tried:

`ffmpeg -i originalvideo.mp4 -i imagetooverlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,635)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4`

Is there a better command that I can use that will overlay the image on the video and rerender it? The image is 1920x1080 and is mostly transparent except for the "bar" that I placed in the correct position. I think that means that it's position doesn't need to be specified, just lined up with the 1920x1080 video.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens with the command you've tried?

Comment: @Gyan It just rerenders the video with no apparent changes. Copying it, essentially.